# Sending email throught gmail

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required.

```
try {  
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();  
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();  
        message.From = new MailAddress("FromMailAddress");  
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress("ToMailAddress"));  
        message.Subject = "Test";  
        message.IsBodyHtml = true; //to make message body as html  
        message.Body = htmlString;  
        smtp.Port = 587;  
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //for gmail host  
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;  
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;  
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("FromMailAddress", "password");  
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;  
        smtp.Send(message);  
    } catch (Exception) {}
```

Less Secure is no more. How can I fix this error?

Comment: yes ,But the gmail "Less secure app access" no option available now . So this code not working

Comment: follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/32336/11657533

Comment: @KrishnaVarma has the right of it, you're most probably getting rejected because of MFA

Comment: @KrishnaVarma i am using window form . so how i can create a app password?

Comment: You can still use Google Workspace: https://blog.elmah.io/how-to-send-emails-from-csharp-net-the-definitive-tutorial/